# how to change datagridview column to int

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to change datagridview column into integer while exporting to excel. column1 has an integer values.

```
myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString();



string[,] ID = new string[myTable.RowCount, 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < myTable.RowCount; i++)
                {
                   ID[i, 0] = myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: error: cannot implicitly type int to string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `int.TryParse` method in order to perform a *safe* conversion from `string` to `integer`:

```
int value;
string input = myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString();
if(int.TryParse(input, out value))
{
    ...
}
```

If your value is not parsable to integer then `TryParse` will return `false`.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

**Convert.ToInt32(string s)**

```
Converts the specified string representation of 
32-bit signed integer equivalent. This calls in turn Int32.Parse () method. 
When s is a null reference, it will return 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException.
```

Example:

```
int num=Convert.ToInt32(myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString());
```

**Int32.Parse(string s)**

```
Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. 
When s is a null reference, it will throw ArgumentNullException.
```

Example:

```
int num=int.Parse(myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString());
```

**Int32.Parse(string, out int)**

```
Converts the specified string representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent 
to out variable, and returns true if it is parsed successfully, false otherwise.
```

Example:

```
string str=myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString();
if(Int32.TryParse(str, out result)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: @user2841795: Which one have you tried? Can you post some code, my friend?

Comment: @user2841795: `D[,]` is string, right? Then why do you want to convert it to `int`? Thats why it causing error.

Comment: I just showed one value in questions, there are 15 columns I am exporting so that's why its string. there are some values which are integer.

Comment: The code you have shown will get executed. Even `integer` values will be treated as `string`. You don't have to convert it for this purpose, my friend. You have to convert the value into `int` **only** if you have any arithmetic calculations needed or if you want to assign the value to a variable of `integer` type.

Comment: Yes you are right this code will be executed successfully but when it exported to excel, it showed as formatted cell error. That's why if it is exported as integer this will not be as error cell.

Comment: @user2841795: If `column1` contains only `integer` then you may want to change the datatype of `ID[,]` to `ineteger`. Like `int ID[,]=new int[myTable.RowCount, 1];`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it via `Int32.TryParse` ([Details in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
//method
public static bool TryParse(
        string s,
        out int result
)

//How to use:
int number;
bool res = Int32.TryParse(myTable.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value.ToString(), out number);

//if parse was successfull
if(res)
{
  //export to Excel
}
else
{
  //throw exception, value was not an int
}
```