# Extracting datagridview values C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How do I calculate Cells with written values in the datagridview?

For example x= Cell1+Cell2 (10+10);   Result:  y1 = 20;

[image]

Comment: You need to convert string to int by using Convert.ToInt32

Comment: Similar question posted before :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480123/how-to-change-datagridview-column-to-int

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230721/error-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-when-calculating-multiple-colum/72238154#72238154 I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to have a DataSource for your DataGridView, in the example below a DataTable is used, third column uses an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0) to add the first two columns together.

Even though a DataGridView works well without a DataSource especially in your case it works better as it ensures a proper type and auto calculations.

And the `BindingSource` allows access to your data without touching the DataGridView.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bindingSource.DataSource = DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
        dataGridView1.DataError += DataGridView1OnDataError;
    }

    private void DataGridView1OnDataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong type");
    }

    private DataTable DataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(int)).Expression = "Col1 + Col2";

        dt.Rows.Add(10, 10);
        return dt;
    }

    private void CurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bindingSource.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var row = ((DataRowView)_bindingSource.Current).Row;
        MessageBox.Show($"Total is {row.Field<int>("Total")}");
    }
}
```